If two subgroups intersect in only the identity, do their cosets intersect in at most one element?
If two subgroups intersect in only the identity, do their cosets intersect in at most one element? I conjecture this is true but have been unable to prove it.
More formally, let group $G$, subgroup $H$, subgroup $K$, with $H \cap K = \{1\}$.  I conjecture that for any $x,y \in G,$ $$|xH \cap yK| \leq 1.$$
I furthermore conjecture that this is true for any $n$: If $|H \cap K| = n$, then $|xH \cap yK| \leq n.$
Is this correct? How can I prove or disprove it?

In general an intersection of cosets $xH \cap yK$ is either empty or a coset of $H \cap K$. Indeed if $z \in xH \cap yK$ then $xH = zH$ and $yK = zK$ so $xH \cap yK = z(H \cap K)$.

Hint: take $xh_1,xh_2\in xH\cap yK$ and consider $h_1^{-1}h_2$. A very similar argument works in the general case.

I'm trying to work this hint.  I assume: Let $h_1, h_2 \in H, k_1, k_2 \in K$ and assume $xh_1 = yk_1, xh_2 = yk_2$.  Then show $h_1 = h_2$ by noting that $h_1h_2^{-1} \in H$, so... somehow concluding that $h_1h_2^{-1}$ must also be in $K$ and (therefore is the identity)?

I'm not able to take this hint any further.  Care to elaborate?

Sorry, I wrote it in the wrong order. You should consider $h_1^{-1}h_2=(xh_1)^{-1}(xh_2)$.
